# Android need close cursor, database, both or none?

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite, cursor

Im searching for some days one solution for my problems with sqlite and android. I read a lot of articles about sqlite and android. I see people saying that you need close CURSOR, and others saying that you need close DATABASE, and others that you need close BOTH, and OTHERS that you dont need close NOTHING, because one Android Engineering post.

In my apps we have too many uses of sqlite.

1 - We store things to be synced.
2 - We add/delete things in background.
3 - We have +/- 10 background services that are started by Alarm Manager to sync somethings.

Everything running in same time, multiple threads and more.

When i get the app, we have a lot and a lot and a lot of crashes from closing the cursor/database while other cursor is opened at the same time. A lot of confusion.

So, after reading, a google engineer post (i dont remember what google group), an answer that you dont need close sqlite cursor or database (i dont remember and i dont know if make difference).

So now in my background services that sync things, i get errors about it:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException
Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=593 (# cursors opened by this proc=593)
```

So what i need do? What is the correct way? What will work with a lot of threads and IntentServices using it?

My sample code today:

```
public static MyInternalObject getFirstAudience() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = UbookProvider.getInstance().getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + UbookContract.MyInternalObject.TABLE_NAME + " LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                return MyInternalObjectService.createFromCursor(cursor);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Im on dark, i dont know a decent way to do it to solve my problems with database in android.

Anyone can help me?

My github ([github.com/prsolucoes](http://github.com/prsolucoes)) have a lot of open-source projects too. I do a lot of things to community, but today is i that need.

Comment: need to close cursor, the database is unnecessary.

Comment: But if you execute direct on database, like this:

`String sql = "DELETE FROM " + UbookContract.MyTable.TABLE_NAME;  

SQLiteDatabase db = UbookProvider.getInstance().getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL(sql);
`

You need close something?

Comment: I don't think you need to close anything after your deleting operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to close your cursors.  One way to do this is to wrap all of your queries in a try/finally statement.

```
Cursor c = null;
try {
    c = db.query(...)
} finally {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

If you are using CursorLoaders (which I highly recommend), then you don't need to close your cursors, because the Loader framework manages it for you.

Comment: But if you execute direct on database, like this:

`String sql = "DELETE FROM " + UbookContract.MyTable.TABLE_NAME;  

SQLiteDatabase db = UbookProvider.getInstance().getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL(sql);
`

You need close something?

Comment: Nope, if you're doing a create / insert / update / delete, you don't need to close anything.  The SQLiteDatabase class has some helpers for delete / update / etc., and I recommend that you use those instead of writing raw SQL.  For example, db.delete(table, where, whereargs) does argument binding for you, and returns the number of affected rows.